# Handling configuration change for async methods

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, async-await, c#-5.0

I have an activity which has an async method in it. This async method is long running. After the async method returns, the UI needs to be updated and some of the controls reference the activity. 
At the moment, everything works correctly if you do not have a configuration change (like screen rotation) while the async task is running. However, if a configuration change happens while it is running, then the exception Activity is destroyed is thrown and the UI is not updated. From what reading I have done, this seems to be because the async method captures context and then tries to update the old context which is of course destroyed after the configuration change.

My question is: What are the best ways to solve this problem or at worst case scenario work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what I ended up doing was encapsulating the async task in another class which held a reference to the current activity, which implemented and interface which defined a method which handles the async response and updates the UI.

The activity held a static variable of the encapsulated async task, and if it was running during a config change, the encapsulated async's task reference to the activity was updated to the new activity.

Answer (score 2):

I personally think you have only three options

- You can disable rotation permanently or temporary, but this is a bad practice

**To disable it permanently** set ConfigurationChanges

```
[Activity(Label = "...", ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
```

**To disable it temporary** while task working you should disable rotation handling,

*disable*

```
this.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Nosensor;
```

*enable*

```
this.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Sensor;
```

- If you are using fragment you can prevent fragment destroy with `RetainInstance = true`. That might work, but i never tested it.
- You can cancel task with `CancelationToken` and restart it in `OnRestoreInstanceState()`
  Here is example how to cancel task

  `{
  CancellationTokenSource cts;
  ...
  // If a download process is already underway, cancel it.
  if (cts != null)
  {
      cts.Cancel();
  }

  // Now set cts to cancel the current process if the button is chosen again.
  CancellationTokenSource newCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
  cts = newCTS;

  try
  {
      //Send cts.Token to carry the message if there is a cancellation request.
      await AccessTheWebAsync(cts.Token);
  }
  // Catch cancellations separately.
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
      ResultsTextBox.Text += "\r\nDownloads canceled.\r\n";
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
      ResultsTextBox.Text += "\r\nDownloads failed.\r\n";
  }
  // When the process is complete, signal that another process can proceed.
  if (cts == newCTS)
      cts = null;
  }`

And in the task

```
async Task AccessTheWebAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
    ...
    // Retrieve the website contents from the HttpResponseMessage.
    byte[] urlContents = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

    // Check for cancellations before displaying information about the 
    // latest site. 
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Agree that disabling rotation is a poor idea so I won't be doing that. It seems as though a fragment with retain state is the cleanest solution. I had not considered cancelling the task but that could also work, but would mean the task may need to be restarted. Given we are C# throwing some events around could also work but that seems messy. Ill mark this as the answer as it offers the most suggestions and has examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of things you could do, but please don't go and disable the phones ability to turn the screen -- that is just going to ignore your users.

At a highlevel you will have to do two things:

1. Make sure the async task keeps running and is not restarted if the activity dies.

You can solve that by moving the task either into the application class or (cleaner) into a headless fragment with setRetainInstance set to true.

1. In the onDestroy method in the activity, remove it from the async task, in the onCreate task give the activity to the async task (if it exist).

This is what prevents the async task from calling the old context and can be done with a simple java setter on the async task. Don't forget to cache the result in the task if the activity is currently not connected.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I agree disabling the rotation is extremely bad and I won't be doing that. The async task never dies on rotation so that's not a problem. It does seem as though a fragment with retain state is the cleanest solution.